# Using update_all to update a date attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, update-all

I have a payments table and I want to be able to update all the date_of_payment fields simultaneously, i.e. with the same date.

In my view I have the following

```
<%= form_tag update_date_payments_path, :class => 'form_for_all', method: :put do %>
    <%= date_select(:date_of_payment, :order => [:year, :month, :day] ) %>
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
  def update_date
    Payment.update_all(params[:date_of_payment])
  end
```

The error I'm getting is:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: {:order=>: UPDATE "payments"
>   SET "{:order=>" = '--- - '':year, :month, :day'' -
>   !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess ! ''}(1i)'':
>   ''2014'' ! ''}(2i)'': ''3'' ! ''}(3i)'': ''24'' '

I must confess that I'm a bit confused about what exactly this error is about. Is the code in my controller incorrect? Or is there something wrong with the form? As I said, I don't fully understand forms yet so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your `payments` schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the syntax of [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all). I think you need something like:

```
Payment.update_all(date_of_payment: params[:date_of_payment])
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thank you! I thought it might be something along those lines :)